# What is Syslog and a Syslog Daemon

Tags: logging, syslog

I'm working with log back and I keep hearing about things written to syslog and a syslog daemon picks these up. So i set up an syslog appender, but do i need to write an daemon for it or this somewhere on the machine already. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think good start is to read [this wikipedia article about Syslog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog)